# coding errors java loop scanner

Tags: java, loops, compiler-errors

im experiencing some errorswith my code and not sure why? im self teaching java. the aim is to get the user to enter integers which will add up in the back ground and once it reaches 999 the system will print you reached 999

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class underaThousand {
public static void main(String args[])  {
    // 
    int sum = 999;
    int total = total+data;
    total = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (data != sum){

    System.out.println("Enter an integer :");
    int data = input.nextInt();
    }
    int total = total+data;
    break;
   {
        System.out.println("You have reached 999");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what error you are facing. One big problem I see though, is that you declare the variable `data` in the while loop, but already want to use it outside of it and even long before that. That doesn't make sense. For a quick fix, declare `data` at the start of `main` like this: `int data = 0;`.

Comment: Also, you try do declare `total`, by refering to itself, before it even exists. Also doesn't make sense. ;D Just declare it with a default value of `0`, so like this: `int total = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `do-while` loop since it is better to start taking the input from the first iteration before the comparison. Moreover, your condition should be when the total becomes greater than or equal to the sum. Also, you should declare the variables once at the beginning.

```
int sum = 999;
int total = 0, data = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer :");
    data = input.nextInt();
    total = total+data;
}while(total < sum);
System.out.println("You have reached 999");
```

Sample output:

```
Enter an integer :
100
Enter an integer :
800
Enter an integer :
99
You have reached 999
```

Comment: many thanks! something i am going to spend more time on

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you cant say`int total = total + data;` because total is null data has not been defined at all. You should just write `int total = 0;` The next thing is that you should not use data in your while loop but instead you should use your total. Because the user can inupt the number the total value can be above 999 which means you should write `while(total<sum)` the calculation of you total meaning `total = total + data` should be in you while loop and you should delete the break. Then close the wile loop and leave the weird { around your System.out...
So the final code would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class underaThousand {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        int sum = 999;
        int total = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (total < sum){

            System.out.println("Enter an integer :");
            int data = input.nextInt();
            total = total+data;
     
        }
        System.out.println("You have reached 999");

    }
}
```

If you have any further questions let me know

Answer (score 0):

**// Analysis of you code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class underaThousand {

  public static void main(String args[])  {
      // 
      int sum = 999;

      int total = total+data; // this line will throw error because data is not defined yet

      total = 0;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      while (data != sum){ // this line will throw error because data is not defined yet

        System.out.println("Enter an integer :");

        int data = input.nextInt();
      }

      // you loop will contineu till you enter 999 as user input
      // you are not using total in condition and also you are not incrementing total 


      int total = total+data; // this line will give error because you are defining total again in same scope


      break; // break is used to break loop or switch cases. you can not use break out side the loop or swoitch case
     {
          System.out.println("You have reached 999");
      }
  }
}
*Note* - Do proper formatting of your code*
```

**// working code**

```
   public static void main(String args[])  {
        // initialize you max sum
        int sum = 999;
        // initialize total with 0
        int total = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // you can not use total != sum
        // in this case if your total cross the 999 then your loop will not break
        // but you reached to 999
        // initially this condition is true because total = 0 and sum = 999
        while (total < sum){
            System.out.println("Enter an integer :");
            int data = input.nextInt();
            total = total + data;
            if(total >= sum){
                System.out.println("You have reached 999");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```